# Unable to build simple boost::regex sample using XCode 4.6.3

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I'm trying to build a really simple boost sample using regex just to try using boost in an XCode project, and I'm running into some strange problems.

First, I downloaded boost 1.53.0, then bootstrapped and built it using the following commands:

`./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=regex`

`./b2 install`

Then I made a really simple regex sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

std::string text(" 192.168.0.1 abc 10.0.0.255 10.5.1 1.2.3.4a 5.4.3.2 ");
const char* pattern =
"\\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
"\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
"\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
"\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b";
boost::regex ip_regex(pattern);

boost::sregex_iterator it(text.begin(), text.end(), ip_regex);
boost::sregex_iterator end;
for (; it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << it->str() << "\n";
    // v.push_back(it->str()); or something similar
}
return 0;
}
```

I added the static library I build (boost_regex.a) to the project setting Build Phases under "Link Binary With Libraries", which also implicitly updated the build setting "Library Search Paths" to point to the library where the .a file is located.

When I try to build, I now get a bunch of linker errors relating to what appears to be the standard C++ library. Here's a snippet:

```
"__gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::_M_detach_all()", referenced from:
      __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::~_Safe_sequence_base() in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::~_Safe_sequence_base() in libboost_regex.a(instances.o)
      __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::~_Safe_sequence_base() in libboost_regex.a(posix_api.o)
      __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::~_Safe_sequence_base() in libboost_regex.a(wide_posix_api.o)
      __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::~_Safe_sequence_base() in libboost_regex.a(winstances.o)
  "__gnu_debug::_Error_formatter::_M_message(__gnu_debug::_Debug_msg_id) const", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const* std::lower_bound<boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const*, boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> >(boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const*, boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const*, boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const&) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      bool std::equal<char const*, char const*>(char const*, char const*, char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      std::lexicographical_compare(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      bool std::lexicographical_compare<signed char const*, signed char const*>(signed char const*, signed char const*, signed char const*, signed char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      std::string::replace(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>, char const*, char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > >::erase(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > >) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::erase(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > > >) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      ...
  "__gnu_debug::_Error_formatter::_M_error() const", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const* std::lower_bound<boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const*, boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> >(boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const*, boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const*, boost::re_detail::character_pointer_range<char> const&) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      bool std::equal<char const*, char const*>(char const*, char const*, char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      std::lexicographical_compare(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      bool std::lexicographical_compare<signed char const*, signed char const*>(signed char const*, signed char const*, signed char const*, signed char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      std::string::replace(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>, char const*, char const*) in libboost_regex.a(c_regex_traits.o)
      std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > >::erase(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > >) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > >::erase(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > > >) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      ...
  "__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator_base::_M_singular() const", referenced from:
      __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::__norm::_List_iterator<std::string>, std::__debug::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >::operator=(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::__norm::_List_iterator<std::string>, std::__debug::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > > const&) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      bool __gnu_debug::operator!=<std::__norm::_List_iterator<std::string>, std::__debug::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::__norm::_List_iterator<std::string>, std::__debug::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > > const&, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::__norm::_List_iterator<std::string>, std::__debug::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > > const&) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      bool __gnu_debug::operator==<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > > >(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > > > const&, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, long> >, std::__debug::map<int, long, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, long> > > > const&) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      bool __gnu_debug::operator==<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > >(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > > const&, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > > const&) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
      bool __gnu_debug::operator!=<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > >(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > > const&, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, std::string> >, std::__debug::map<int, std::string, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, std::string> > > > const&) in libboost_regex.a(cregex.o)
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this? I can't think of any simpler test case....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but when I tried using Boost in Xcode a few years ago, I found that I could not use the prebuilt libs. Instead, I had to add all the files into the Xcode project. The reason for that is probably that boost's own install scripts build the libs with options that your Xcode project doesn't match. But if you let Xcode build it all, you're good.